# How to get the first element of the specified source column for each element in the given target table

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to show only the initial date of delivery for specific orders.
There could be many changes made to delivery dates but I want to show the very first one put in the system.

I tried with MIN but it gave me an error that it's not a timestamp data type so I tried with row number over partition by.... Here's the code:

```
  SELECT 
    ,'Initial Date' AS "ACTIVITY_NAME"
    ,TMP_RDD."EVENTTIME" AS "Requested Delivery Date"
    ,TMP_RDD."VBELN" AS "SO Number"
   
FROM( SELECT 
      "Requested Delivery Date", 
      "SO Number", 
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY "SO Number" ORDER BY "Requested Delivery Date" ) AS "RN"
FROM TMP_RDD ) AS TMP_RDD WHERE  TMP_RDD."RN" = 1
```

Here's the sample table with changes to delivery dates:

| SO number (header) | Requested Delivery Date (value old) | Requested Delivery Date (value new) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 012 | 01.07.2022 | 03.07.2022 |
| 012 | 03.07.2022 | 05.07.2022 |
| 012 | 05.07.2022 | 20.06.2022 |

The problem is that it gives me the earliest date of all which isn't always correct as for example the initial delivery date could have been the 1st of July but the code gives me the the 20th of June.

Do you have any idea of what I could use here instead? In PQL, the formula that always works is PU_FIRST, what would be the equivalent of this in SQL (I'm also getting an error while trying to use FIRST_VALUE)

Comment: can you please add your table with data and which dates you want of the sample data, we need a [mre]

Comment: First value needs also a column name to know the first value

Comment: @nbk Thanks! I edited the message. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: so you have 3 columns and two have the same name, if you want to keep the "old values" you need another table where you keep the changes and the old and new date, when you overwrite a column the data is lost, as long you don'thavbe a system that keeps them, you could also have a column initial date (value old) and save there the information, if there is only one change or only the inital value is relevant for some thing

Comment: @nbk I do have change logs and all dates are stored, the only thing I'm struggling with is the SQL script that would show me the FIRST date put in the system and not the earliest one :(

Comment: you need to usion all TMP_RDD  and the logs and then  use row_number, you data model is nozt that clear to me, as you didn't provide a mre with all reöevant data, why do you have 3 dates in your sampple, how do you knpow which changed dates belong towhom ....